# invalid token in joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

I am using joomla for my website

I have a function in my controller like this

```
function genericLogis(){
            $model  = &$this->getModel( JRequest::getCmd( 'view' ) );
            $view   = &$this->getView( JRequest::getCmd( 'view' ), 'html' );
            $view->setModel($model, true);
            $view->setLayout('logistical'); 
            $view->logistical(); 
    }
```

and in my model I have this

```
function getBasicos(){
        JRequest::checkToken() or jexit( 'Invalid Token' );
            $plantilla=1;
            $db=& JFactory::getDBO();
            $query= "SELECT *
            FROM ".$db->nameQuote('#__accedo_materiales')."
            WHERE ".$db->nameQuote('plantilla')."=".$db->quote($plantilla).";";
            $db->setQuery( $query );
            $materialesBasicos=$db->loadObjectList();
            return $materialesBasicos;
        }
```

and my view is a form like this

```
<?php defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access'); ?>

<form action="index.php?option=<?php echo $option; ?>&amp;view=<?php echo $view; ?>" method="post" name="adminForm">
    .....

    <input type="hidden" name="option" value="<?php echo $option; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="view" value="materiales" />
    <input type="hidden" name="task" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="boxchecked" value="0" />
    <?php echo JHTML::_( 'form.token' ); ?>
</form>
```

why when I click on the link to see this form I see Invalid Token!!

Comment: try this `<input type="hidden" name="task" value="genericLogis" />`

Comment: Could you also provide the link you are clicking on?